# Ajax.BeginForm unobtrusive ajax not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form inside a partial view, the form is not firing the client side javascript method specified in the AjaxOptions and I cannot see why.

I have the following form.

```
@model QuickContact

<div id="quickContactForm" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 push-md-9 box">

        <h4>Quick Contact</h4>

        <div id="contactForm"></div>

        <p>
            For an instant callback simply fill in the form below.
        </p>

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            "QuickContact",
            "Contact",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                OnFailure = "contact.onFailure",
                OnBegin = "contatc.onBegin",
                OnComplete = "contact.onComplete",
                OnSuccess = "contact.onSuccess",
                UpdateTargetId = "quickContactForm"
            }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your name..." } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your telephone..." } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Telephone, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        }

        <div id="loading" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="text-lg-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

with my js is;

```
var contact = {

    onBegin: function() {
        console.log("loading...");
        $('#loading').show();
    },

    onComplete: function() {
        console.log("complete");
        $("#loading").hide();
    },

    onFailure: function(ajaxContext) {
        console.log("error occured.");
        var response = ajaxContext.responseText;
        alert("Error Code [" + ajaxContext.ErrorCode + "] " + response);
        $('#loading').hide();
    },

    onSuccess: function(result) {
        // enable unobtrusive validation for the contents
        // that was injected into the <div id="result"></div> node
        console.log("ajax success func");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(result));
    }
};
```

I have also installed the nuget package for unobtrusive-ajax using

> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

and in my web.config I have

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

finally, I have added the unobtrusive-ajax link to my bundling;

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/tether/tether.js"));
```

I get no console errors at all but the POST is hitting the controller action and none of my ajax console logs are registered.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Just make sure that your `OnBegin` property value is correct. It should be  `contact.onBegin` not `contatc.onBegin`

`onBegin` function is defined on `contact`, not `contatc`

This should work.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                        "QuickContact",
                        "Contact",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            OnFailure = "contact.onFailure",
                            OnBegin = "contact.onBegin",
                            OnComplete = "contact.onComplete",
                            OnSuccess = "contact.onSuccess",
                            UpdateTargetId = "quickContactForm"
                        }))
{
  <!-- Your form controls goes here -->

}
```

I tried this code and it logged the messages to my console.

You may also want to include `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` library as well.

Comment: Hi Shyju, sorry that was just a typo in my question. As I mentioned everything appears to be right (i'm testing in chrome by the way and using bootstrap v4). Theres no errors in the console either, but is there any ordering required for the js files?

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, you need `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` as well. So with all these code when you click submit what is happening ? Do you see the console.log messages in your browser console ? Any errors when submit is clicked ? The above code totally worked for me